# bootstrap - bootstrap works only after resizing

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm developing a small application on codepen

http://codepen.io/asamolion/full/VjKzYV/

But the problem is that the bootstrap css doesn't load on page load. But it works when I resize the browser.

e.g. if I make the browser smaller and maximize it again then it will work but it's not working on first page load.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Here is my of the central div

```
#quote-machine {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10%;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 12px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px #AAA, 0 5px 10px #CCC;
    min-height: 60vh;
    min-width: 50vw;
}
```

Here are some screenshots

**First load**
[image: First Load]

**Minimize** 
[image: Minimize]

**Maximize** 
[image: Maximize]

It's width should be like "Maximize" on the first load but it isn't and I can't find the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works well for me.. How would you like to describe not working?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I've added screenshots. please see them.

Comment: Sorry we have no Idea what you mean by "Working only after resizing"  What is the desired look before resizing and after?

Comment: Texts are different.. How would you expect width to be same??

Comment: @GuruprasadRao even with same text the issue is same

Comment: First off you're using bootstrap and then you've added display: flex; on body so I'm not entirely sure what that combination will do.  Second, you have min-height and min-width set to viewport H and W. Which will only come into play if a browser viewport meets those minimum size conditions by either size or text content.

Essentially all this telling quote-machine to expand itself to the max width of the text to point X if it's large and the screen is maximized.  If the text is count is small then quote-machine will shrink to a minimum of 50vw.

Comment: To do what I think you're looking for you would need to bump up the min-width:  to the size your looking for and then use Media queries to resize quote-machine appropriately I.E @media (max-width: 600px)

Comment: @asamolion Have you fixed your codepen? Because I don't see any of your problems now..

Comment: @Sriram No, but I think I've found the issue. Basically it happens because I'm dynamically loading the text using ajax. I'll have to re-adjust my css such that the responsive container remains centered with or without content.

Comment: @asamolion I've updated my answer, you should give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
```

instead of using all the grid classes,

```
<div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">
```

try with specific class and see

Comment: The issue is still same

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED: You can manually trigger it by setting the width of the fluid container on an ajax callback which is sort of hacky, but you only need to do it once.

Here's a link to my working example: [Link to working example using simple window resize](http://codepen.io/irmoathlete/pen/qNaoVX)

```
.done(function() {
  $('.container-fluid').css('width', '100%');
})
```